# Simple 5-star but want to be responsive

Tags: html, css, rating

I got this css from:

> https://www.cssscript.com/simple-5-star-rating-system-with-css-and-html-radios

But I want the star rating to be responsive to the screen.

Include the required Font Awesome for star icons.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

HTML and CSS for a five star rating widget using Html radio buttons.

```css
div.stars {
  width: 270px;
  display: inline-block;
}

input.star { display: none; }

label.star {
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #444;
  transition: all .2s;
}

input.star:checked ~ label.star:before {
  content: '\f005';
  color: #FD4;
  transition: all .25s;
}

input.star-5:checked ~ label.star:before {
  color: #FE7;
  text-shadow: 0 0 20px #952;
}

input.star-1:checked ~ label.star:before { color: #F62; }

label.star:hover { transform: rotate(-15deg) scale(1.3); }

label.star:before {
  content: '\f006';
  font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="stars">
  <form action="">
    <input class="star star-5" id="star-5" type="radio" name="star"/>
    <label class="star star-5" for="star-5"></label>
    <input class="star star-4" id="star-4" type="radio" name="star"/>
    <label class="star star-4" for="star-4"></label>
    <input class="star star-3" id="star-3" type="radio" name="star"/>
    <label class="star star-3" for="star-3"></label>
    <input class="star star-2" id="star-2" type="radio" name="star"/>
    <label class="star star-2" for="star-2"></label>
    <input class="star star-1" id="star-1" type="radio" name="star"/>
    <label class="star star-1" for="star-1"></label>
  </form>
</div>
```

5 star rating is good, but how to make it responsive?

Thanks to all...

Comment: do you want the stars decrease size or in a new line?

Comment: How is it not responsive already?

Comment: remove the width from div.stars to see it responsive

Comment: as @AIqbalRaj said see here:https://jsfiddle.net/6j3mcv78/

Comment: when I change the font size to 100px in label.star and change the screen display. 5 stars did not change.

Comment: do not change the  `font size` remove the `width`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have given width for div.stars. You can use media queries. like this, (https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    div.stars {
        width: 150px;
    }
}
```

Comment: @AzizYanuarSaputra Thank you. Hope this will be work for you

Answer (score 0):

```css
div.stars {
  max-width: 270px;
  display: inline-block;
  width:100%
}

input.star { display: none; }

label.star {
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #444;
  transition: all .2s;
}

input.star:checked ~ label.star:before {
  content: '\f005';
  color: #FD4;
  transition: all .25s;
}

input.star-5:checked ~ label.star:before {
  color: #FE7;
  text-shadow: 0 0 20px #952;
}

input.star-1:checked ~ label.star:before { color: #F62; }

label.star:hover { transform: rotate(-15deg) scale(1.3); }

label.star:before {
  content: '\f006';
  font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="stars">
  <form action="">
    <input class="star star-5" id="star-5" type="radio" name="star"/>
    <label class="star star-5" for="star-5"></label>
    <input class="star star-4" id="star-4" type="radio" name="star"/>
    <label class="star star-4" for="star-4"></label>
    <input class="star star-3" id="star-3" type="radio" name="star"/>
    <label class="star star-3" for="star-3"></label>
    <input class="star star-2" id="star-2" type="radio" name="star"/>
    <label class="star star-2" for="star-2"></label>
    <input class="star star-1" id="star-1" type="radio" name="star"/>
    <label class="star star-1" for="star-1"></label>
  </form>
</div>
```